# how to use Obtion menu in two class

Tags: android

Hi i have Use Menu in 2 class  this is my Menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_seting"
        android:title="Setting">
    </item>
 </menu>
```

in class A i have use this

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
        return true;
    }

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.SavedList:

        Intent intent = new Intent(

        A.this,

        SetPreference.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        return true;

}
return true;
}
```

and in class b i have use

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
        return true;
    }


public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.SavedList:

        Intent intent = new Intent(

        b.this,

        SetPreference.class);

        startActivity(intent);

        return true;

}
return true;
}
```

in one class b its working fine but in class its not working please tell me where i m doing wrong please help me i am new n android

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Intent that time why need two different class with same body. What I suggest is In case body write a Intent for class B menu.. see whether work or not .
Go through the documentation of the Intent in Android and Also menu Android documentation you will find more information .

Comment: But Dear when i display in one class its working fine But in another class its not working

Comment: use that another class as second intent